# Monogame - Loading between levels

Tags: c#, .net, xna, monogame

I'm currently building a 2D platformer using Monogame and I'm having a bit of an issue. The way I have designed my game is that I use an `array` to draw out the map of tiles, which all have collision, like this:

```
protected override void LoadContent()
{
    map.Generate(new int[,] {

    // 0 = no tile drawn
    // 3 = tile is drawn

    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
    {3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,},
    {3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,},

    }, 57); // size 
}
```

However I'm trying to think of a way that allows me to load another array that of course would have tiles placed differently once the player reaches a certain point, *for example, using the array in my question, if the player spawns on the left and reaches the last tile on the right*.

What would be the simplest way of trying to accomplish this?

Comment: It sounds like what you're asking is how to unload the previous level and load a new level once the player has completed the current level? Maybe [this answer](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/5615/disposing-only-certain-resources-in-xna/) will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a good reference, supplied by Microsoft. This will allow you to examine and breakdown a working version of a 2D platformer.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd254916%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx

In brief, this is what I would expect to implement, regarding a 2D platformer and several levels (not scrolling).

1. Define the total screens, block size, total blocks to draw on the screen.
2. Create an array of screen block data.
3. Set the game screen number to  your start screen.
4. Use that number to reference into the screen block data array and draw the blocks on screen.

The above data could be generated as a binary file and loaded in at start-up, or for ease created as an array of screne block data within your game class.

I'm sure the tutorial I've linked will guide you in the development of your game.